# <canvas> Drawing multiple Rects and moving them all from one side to another

Tags: canvas, translate

I am trying to get my head around the .
I want to draw a bar at the right end of the canvas, then on the next frame, move the bar one "place" to the left, and draw a second bar on the right end. then on the third frame, move both bars one place to the left and draw a third bar and so on...

> [ | | | |1], [ | | |1|2],[ | |1|2|3]

it have it working but like this i have to write the context.strokeRect() line for every bar...

```
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.strokeRect(490, 100, 8, width[i]);
    context.strokeRect(480, 100, 8, width[i-1]);
    context.strokeRect(470, 100, 8, width[i-2]);
    context.stroke();
```

this can't be the best way of doing it..?

Answer (score 0):

**[ Change: have bars originate on right and push existing bars leftward ]**

Here's code that draws the bars leftward:

```
for(var i=widthIndex, x=maxX; i>=0 && x>0; i--, x-=8){
    ctx.strokeRect(x,100,8,width[i]);
    if(parseInt(i/10)==i/10){
        ctx.fillRect(x,100,8,width[i]);
    }
}
widthIndex++;
```

[image]

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/SHY92/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var maxX=270;
    var maxBars=parseInt(maxX/8);
    var width=[];
    var widthIndex=0;
    var countdown=5;
    ctx.fillStyle="red";

    // create some test data
    for(var i=0;i<250;i++){
        width.push(20+Math.random()*10);
    }

    animate();

    function animate(){
        if(widthIndex>width.length-1){return;}

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        if(countdown-->0){ return; }

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        for(var i=widthIndex, x=maxX; i>=0 && x>0; i--, x-=8){
            ctx.strokeRect(x,100,8,width[i]);
            if(parseInt(i/10)==i/10){
                ctx.fillRect(x,100,8,width[i]);
            }
        }

        widthIndex++;

        countdown=5;

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick reply.
but doesnt solve my problem.

in your example every new bar is drawn after the last one. but i am trying to draw all bars at the same spot, but keeping and moving all other bars behind it.



[http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/8g9AH/][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/8g9AH/

Comment: I've updated my answer to draw new bars on the right and "push" existing bars leftward.  Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

- Simply draw the bar on the right side with a solid background
- "blit" the canvas to the left and repeat with the next bar

Some setup values:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    barWidth = 20,                   // width of bar and blit delta
    w = canvas.width,
    h = canvas.height,
    maxHeight = h * 0.5;             // for our random bar (demo)
```

To draw the bar on the right side:

```
function drawBar() {
    // get a random height
    var bh = maxHeight * Math.random() + maxHeight;

    // we're gonna need a solid background
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.fillRect(w - barWidth - 1, 0, barWidth - 1, h);  // bar area at right

    // draw a random bar
    ctx.fillStyle = '#902';
    ctx.fillRect(w - barWidth - 1, 0, barWidth - 1, bh);
}
```

The above would of course be replaced with your actual bar method - you only need to draw in a new bar at the same position, just change height etc. The solid background is important as we draw on top of ourselves (background isn't cleared automatically).

To "blit" you just draw the canvas to itself but destination x reduced with `barWidth`:

```
ctx.drawImage(canvas, barWidth, 0, w - barWidth, h,  // source
                      0, 0, w - barWidth, h);        // destination
```

Then make it all work together:

```
(function loop() {
    blit();
    drawBar();
    setTimeout(loop, 100);
})();
```

### [Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/53hTu/)

[image: Snapshot]